# Averaging unequal length x-y pair data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sparse set of x-y pair data that I need to average.  I think I can brute force the issue using a series of search indexing operations (since the x-data should match when overlapping), but I feel like there should be a better solution that I'm missing..

[image]

I started writing code to generate random data, but it might be easier just to show the plot here (plotted in log scale to highlight the non-matching data lengths).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is code to randomly generate data to match the format the data of interest.  Averaging of ys is what I'm after while maintaining their x-position.

```
from random import random

# Constructing random example data

x1 = range(1,100)
x2 = range(40,150)
x3 = range(30, 200)
xList = [x1, x2, x3]

y1 = [None for x in x1]
y2 = [None for x in x2]
y3 = [None for x in x3]
yList = [y1, y2 ,y3]

for i in range(0,len(xList)):
    for j in range(0,len(xList[i])):
        yList[i][j] = random()
```

Below, I'll show my brute force method.  I haven't generalized it into for loops yet, but just to take a look, this is how I would do it. Sorry, I'm not a programmer by trade, so this may be a very roundabout way of doing it.

```
# Brute force method
minX = min(x1[0], x2[0], x3[0])
maxX = max(x1[-1], x2[-1], x3[-1])
xAll = range(minX, maxX + 1)

x1startIndex = xAll.index(x1[0])
x2startIndex = xAll.index(x2[0])
x3startIndex = xAll.index(x3[0])

x1endIndex = xAll.index(x1[-1])
x2endIndex = xAll.index(x2[-1])
x3endIndex = xAll.index(x3[-1])

from numpy import nan, arange, vstack, nanmean

x1EmptyHead = [nan for x in arange(0,x1startIndex)]  #create empty head
x2EmptyHead = [nan for x in arange(0,x2startIndex)]
x3EmptyHead = [nan for x in arange(0,x3startIndex)]

x1EmptyTail = [nan for x in arange(x1endIndex+1,len(xAll))]  #create empty tail
x2EmptyTail = [nan for x in arange(x2endIndex+1,len(xAll))]
x3EmptyTail = [nan for x in arange(x3endIndex+1,len(xAll))]

y1EqualLength = x1EmptyHead + y1 + x1EmptyTail  #create equal length y-data
y2EqualLength = x2EmptyHead + y2 + x2EmptyTail
y3EqualLength = x3EmptyHead + y3 + x3EmptyTail

yConcat = vstack((y1EqualLength, y2EqualLength, y3EqualLength)) # concatenate
yMean = nanmean(yConcat, axis=0)    # arithmetic mean ignoring NaNs
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. For one thing -- continuous curves are not usually described as being "sparse".

Comment: Do you want to average all of the points together? All of the xs and ys? You'll need to show some code and talk about the data types involved rather than showing a plot of some functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, what you're after can be done very cleanly in `pandas` because you can take advantage of its indexing alignment.  For example, if I start with a smaller version of your example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(y,index=x) for x,y in zip(xList, yList)], axis=1)
df["avg"] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

gives me

```
>>> df
           0         1         2       avg
1   0.956034       NaN       NaN  0.956034
2   0.947827       NaN       NaN  0.947827
3   0.056551       NaN       NaN  0.056551
4   0.084872  0.835499       NaN  0.460185
5        NaN  0.735970       NaN  0.735970
6        NaN  0.669730       NaN  0.669730
7        NaN  0.308136  0.581204  0.444670
8        NaN  0.605944  0.158383  0.382164
9        NaN  0.606802  0.430670  0.518736
10       NaN       NaN  0.393532  0.393532
11       NaN       NaN  0.723012  0.723012
12       NaN       NaN  0.994820  0.994820
13       NaN       NaN  0.949395  0.949395
14       NaN       NaN  0.544177  0.544177
```

where the `mean` automatically ignores the NaN values appropriately.  This can then be plotted:

[image: demo pix]

Comment: this works perfectly. I thought of using `pandas` but for some reason had decided I wanted to keep the imports light. Now I don't remember why. Thanks!